# How to declaratively set a global action handler in eclipse rcp?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Eclipse introduced the command framework some time ago and since then you can configure e.g. popup menues, toolbars, etc. declaratively. See [Menu Contributions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions).

For now I use a `CommonActionProvider` (as proposed [here](http://scribbledideas.blogspot.com/2006/06/building-common-navigator-_115067357450703178.html)) to set a global action handler. e.g. for the `open` action that is used when a user double-clicks on an item in my view.

```
 private IAction myAction = ....;

 public void fillActionBars(IActionBars actionBars){
      if(myAction.isEnabled()){
           actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ICommonActionConstants.OPEN, myAction);
      }
 }
```

I want to use a declarative contribution instead, because I can use my command handlers then and do not need to create an action just to hook into the global action handler.

This approach would also be better, because I can then make use of the [Command Expressions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions).

Does anyone know how to do this?

or

Does anyone know how to omit the re-definition of my command as an action?
Because I can't set a command as global action handler.

Comment: I don't think you can, the RetargetAction stuff doesn't have a declarative contribution.

Comment: How do you handle the case when you contribute a command to a popup menu, but you also want that command to be the open action (double-click).

Comment: The double click action generally has to be an `OpenListener` in the code that sets up to Tree/Table Viewer. The common navigator code may provide something else for that but since I don't use that I can't tell you what.

Comment: Ok, thanks greg-449.

Comment: I also had this issue. The best I could come up with was an adapter action that reflects appearance and enablement of the command it wraps and executes the command when run. Let me know if you would be interested in the sources.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Yes, I'm interessted in that code. For now I copied the `org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.CommandAction` and modified it. It works, but causes entries in the error log. So another solution would be nice.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann I just created an extension and a `GlobalActionProvider`. The `GlobalActionProvider` can be used as an `actionProvider` in a `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` configuration. It reads contributions to it's own extension and creates `CommandAction`s that it binds as global action handler when it's `fillActionBars` is invoked. Works good and now it is completely declarative. :)

Comment: Glad to read you solved your issue. Perhaps, you may want to self-answer your question if you think it is of general interest.